# Slow remote desktop connection to VPS

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, vps, local-area-network

When I use Windows 7's remote desktop connection to our company's VPS (Win Server 2008 32bit) I receive a very slow connection - most of the times it actually grinds down to a complete halt. This is in contrast to my team mates which have no problem remoting to the VPS.

I'm using a brand new Dell Studio 1558 laptop with Intel Core i7 and 4GB RAM with a clean installation of Windows 7 64bit Ultimate.

Any suggestions for how to diagnose \ solve \ workaround the problem would be appreciated.

**UPDATES:**

- I checked, and it seems the problem exists with all the computers connected to my home LAN. Once I take my laptop to the nearest coffee shop it works fine. What could be the problem with the LAN?

Comment: Are you all using the same internet connection?

Answer (score 2):

MTU issues can cause RDP connections to hang/freeze. To eliminate this as a possibility, you might try lowering your MTU to see if it makes any difference: http://www.richard-slater.co.uk/archives/2009/10/23/change-your-mtu-under-vista-or-windows-7/

Comment: I took my laptop outside my LAN and it worked fine. Could it still be an MTU problem?

Comment: Also, I tried the test suggested by the link you posted, and it seems I can ping my VPS's IP with the max MTU (1472 + 28 for header), so I'm not sure it's an MTU problem...

Comment: Just to confirm, did you do this MTU test inside or outside the LAN?